# Turn off https in Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, https

When Docker is running http://localhost redirects to https://localhost. The output of `docker-compose up` has these two lines, which suggest to me one of the Docker services is doing a 301 redirect to https.

```
php_1      | 172.29.0.8 -  13/Apr/2021:14:51:24 +0000 "GET /index.php" 301
nginx_1    | 172.29.0.2 - - [13/Apr/2021:14:51:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4476.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Is my thinking correct, and if so how can I prevent it?

If it's relevant this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:10.1-2.3.3
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
      MYSQL_USER: drupal
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      #      - ./mariadb-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # Place init .sql file(s) here.
      - ./.persist/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:cached # I want to manage volumes manually.
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=mariadb"
      - "traefik.port=3306"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost"

  php:
    # 2. Images without Drupal – wodby/drupal-php:[PHP_VERSION]-[STABILITY_TAG].
    #    image: wodby/drupal-php:7.1-2.4.3
    #    image: wodby/drupal-php:7.0-2.1.0
    #    image: wodby/drupal-php:5.6-2.1.0
    #    image: wodby/drupal-php:5.3-2.1.0
    build: ./build/php
    environment:
      DOCKER_LOCAL: 1
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      DB_HOST: mariadb
      DB_USER: drupal
      DB_PASSWORD: drupal
      DB_NAME: drupal
      DB_DRIVER: mysql
      PHP_XDEBUG: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_DEFAULT_ENABLE: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK: 0 # This is needed to respect remote.host setting bellow
      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: "10.254.254.254" # You will also need to 'sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.254.254.254'
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=localhost" # Needed for xdebug for drush commands.
      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_AUTOSTART: 0
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./.persist/public:/var/www/html/docroot/sites/default/files
      - ./.persist/private:/private

  nginx:
    # wodby/drupal-nginx:[DRUPAL_VERSION]-[NGINX_VERSION]-[STABILITY_TAG].
    image: wodby/drupal-nginx:8-1.13-2.4.2
    #    image: wodby/drupal-nginx:7-1.10-2.1.0
    #    image: wodby/drupal-nginx:6-1.10-2.1.0
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_CONTENT_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/docroot
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./.persist/public:/var/www/html/docroot/sites/default/files
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=nginx"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:localhost,{subdomain:[a-z0-9-\\.]+}.localhost, {subdomain:[a-z0-9]+}.ngrok.io'

  #  varnish:
  #    image: wodby/drupal-varnish:4.1-2.1.0
  #    depends_on:
  #      - nginx
  #    environment:
  #      VARNISH_SECRET: secret
  #      VARNISH_BACKEND_HOST: nginx
  #      VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT: 80
  #    labels:
  #      - 'traefik.backend=varnish'
  #      - 'traefik.port=6081'
  #      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:varnish.localhost'

  redis:
    image: wodby/redis:3.2-2.1.0

  #  pma:
  #    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  #    environment:
  #      PMA_HOST: mariadb
  #      PMA_USER: drupal
  #      PMA_PASSWORD: drupal
  #      PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
  #      PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
  #    labels:
  #      - 'traefik.backend=pma'
  #      - 'traefik.port=80'
  #      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:pma.localhost'

  solr:
    ## wodby/drupal-solr:[DRUPAL_VERSION]-[SOLR_VERSION]-[STABILITY_TAG].
    image: wodby/drupal-solr:8-6.4-2.0.0
    ##    image: wodby/drupal-solr:8-6.3-2.0.0
    #    image: wodby/drupal-solr:8-5.5-2.0.0
    ##    image: wodby/drupal-solr:7-6.4-2.0.0
    ##    image: wodby/drupal-solr:7-6.3-2.0.0
    ##    image: wodby/drupal-solr:7-5.5-2.0.0
    environment:
      SOLR_HEAP: 1024m
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./.persist/solr:/opt/solr/server/solr/core1:delegated
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=solr"
      - "traefik.port=8983"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:solr.local"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=mailhog"
      - "traefik.port=8025"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mailhog.localhost"

  #  node:
  #    image: node:7-alpine
  #    working_dir: /app
  #    labels:
  #      - 'traefik.backend=node'
  #      - 'traefik.port=3000'
  #      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:front.localhost'
  #    expose:
  #      - "3000"
  #    volumes:
  #      - ./path/to/your/single-page-app:/app
  #    command: sh -c 'npm install && npm run start'

  #  memcached:
  #    image: wodby/memcached:1.4-2.0.0

  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO --defaultEntryPoints='https,http' --entryPoints='Name:https Address::443 TLS:/certs/local.crt,/certs/local.key' --entryPoints='Name:http Address::80'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    #      - '8080:8080' # Dashboard
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./.persist/certs:/certs
```

If the answer lies inside the Docker containers can it be moved to docker-compose.yml so it persists?

Comment: Docker doesn't manipulate traffic in this way at all.  If I was going to guess at something it'd probably be the Nginx or Traefik configuration.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. I've spent the past 2 days looking and am at a loss. This stuff is confusing as heck.

Comment: @DerekJohnson new browsers like chrome has setting HSTS "Always Secure SSL" on option, that means it will always redirect from http to https it could be your problem
https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker ngix/traefik 301 redirecting http to https in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160206/docker-ngix-traefik-301-redirecting-http-to-https-in-localhost)