# Docker ngix/traefik 301 redirecting http to https in localhost

Tags: docker, nginx, traefik

This is a follow up to [Turn off https in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67087945/turn-off-https-in-docker) with some more information. I still haven't figured it out.

I asked in the Docker slack group and they are convinced it's coming from the nginx or traefik config.

In Firefox there is a SSL_ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT error, and in Chrome it's the similar ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT. I'm not finding out much about either of those by searching.

My nginx config:

```
user                                    nginx;
daemon                                  off;
worker_processes                        auto;
error_log                               /proc/self/fd/2 debug;

events {
  worker_connections                  1024;
  multi_accept                        on;
}

http {
  include                             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type                        application/octet-stream;
  fastcgi_buffers                     16 32k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size                 32k;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors            on;
  fastcgi_read_timeout                900;
  include                             fastcgi_params;
  access_log                          /proc/self/fd/1;
  port_in_redirect                    off;
  send_timeout                        600;
  sendfile                            on;
  client_body_timeout                 600;
  client_header_timeout               600;
  client_max_body_size                256M;
  client_body_buffer_size             16K;
  client_header_buffer_size           4K;
  large_client_header_buffers         8 16K;
  keepalive_timeout                   60;
  keepalive_requests                  100;
  reset_timedout_connection           off;
  tcp_nodelay                         on;
  tcp_nopush                          on;
  server_tokens                       off;
  upload_progress                     uploads 1m;

  gzip                                on;
  gzip_buffers                        16 8k;
  gzip_comp_level                     2;
  gzip_http_version                   1.1;
  gzip_min_length                     20;
  gzip_types                          text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon application/vnd.ms-fonto
  gzip_vary                           on;
  gzip_proxied                        any;
  gzip_disable                        msie6;

  add_header                          X-XSS-Protection '1; mode=block';
  add_header                          X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  add_header                          X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

  map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fastcgi_https {
      default $https;
      http '';
      https on;
  }

  map $uri $no_slash_uri {
      ~^/(?<no_slash>.*)$ $no_slash;
  }


  upstream backend {
      server php:9000;
  }


  include conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

My nginx.conf.default:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

My docker-compose.yml is unchanged from the previous question.

I've looked for anthing resembling traefik config and can't find anything.

Things I've tried so far:

- swapping things round inside the `map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fastcgi_https` i.e. `default $http; http on; https '';`
- deleting that whole map block
- removing the references to https in line 140 of docker-compose.yml
- removing line 143 from docker-compose.yml
- removing line 147 from docker-compose.yml
- creating a self-signed certificate for localhost
- sackcloth and ashes

I'm genuinely at a loss, any help appreciated.

Comment: Judging by the logs from the previous post, redirect comes from `index.php`. If it was `nginx` or `traefik` the request wouldn't come to PHP service, i.e. you wouldn't have got this line in logs: `php_1      | 172.29.0.8 -  13/Apr/2021:14:51:24 +0000 "GET /index.php" 301`

Comment: So you have the issue when using the simple Nginx configuration you posted here (HTTP to HTTPS), with only index.html and HTTP server? Can you paste the logs in this case, as in your previous post there is PHP involved? What you want is to disable HTTPS, and so use HTTP only on your localhost right?

Comment: Do you accept an answer if you can get it working with https with a locally signed cert? if so i can post a answer

Comment: What ever happened to creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? :-)  It seems like there is plenty of room for simplification as a first step to tracing problems here.  The redirect seems to come from nginx or PHP, my guess is maybe Drupal (?) redirecting http to https?  What does `index.php` look like?  If you add a plain text `index.html` can you access that? Administrative request - please don't create duplicate questions. Now this one has the bounty you should close the first and copy all the info from there here.

Comment: Sorry folks, should have mentioned this is Drupal, not a plain HTML page.

Comment: @Mtxz yes you're correct. I want to disable https. I'm setting up on a new laptop and it was http on the old laptop and for all my colleagues.

Comment: @mahen3d yes I will, definitely.

Comment: @DerekJohnson do you also get redirected when using a simple HTML file? and the Nginx config you posted (:80 only)? If so, I would first try to clear browser cache or try with another browser: they can cache the redirection, and so remember that once your domain redirected from HTTP to HTTPS (mostly cause of PHP) and so continue to do so. If not, we'll continue investigate :)

Comment: @Mtxz the redirect occurs after clearning the browser cache. It does not happen when I put a test html file in docroot e.g. localhost/test.html

Comment: So the redirect comes from PHP. What are you using as PHP scripts? Simple scripts? Framework? We need details about the PHP side, as it seems the redirect comes from it.

Comment: @Mtxz it's Drupal

Comment: Ok. Do you have any htaccess file? Is the base_url of drupal HTTP? Is there any in-database URL configured with HTTPS?

Comment: Check your drupal settings.php to see if any URL is hardcoded with HTTPS, or that the HTTPS configuration is ON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231505/discussion-between-derek-johnson-and-mtxz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more tests from OP, and other user's comments: it seemed that the redirection  (HTTP to HTTPS) was occurring after Nginx handled the request.

OP also tested using a single index.html file and was not redirected to HTTPS: confirming that the redirection came from PHP (or at least not from Nginx).

The next steps were to look into Drupal configuration, and/or htaccess configuration. OP changed some Drupal configuration (about redirections), and successfully got the drupal setup page working with HTTP only.

Best in those case is always to try to pin-point the where the issue come from:

- Make your Nginx configuration minimal: simple index.html
- Clear browser cache regularly: they sometimes cache the redirection
- Check/remove htaccess to see if behavior changes
- Finally, if Nginx is "clean" from any issue, and htaccess doesn't seem to be the issue: it's mostly "after", so the issue may come from "to who Nginx is sending the request"
- From "large" frameworks/CMS like Drupal, Woocommerce, Laravel... Redirection is usually handled "easily" from configuration files or DB settings.
- When you have custom code handling redirections: it'll need debugging